# An equivalent for Locale.forLanguageTag for minSdk less than 21?

Tags: android, locale

I want to use the **Locale** method **forLanguageTag()**.

However, the device minSdk that is required for using it is 21.

Since I want my app to be compatible with as many devices as possible, I need an equivalent for lower minSdk.

Is anybody familiar with such alternative?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Nevermind, found one now, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Add Apache Commons Lang packet by adding this to **build.gradle**:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

Use this function:

```
LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `Locale("languageTag", "countryCode")` straight away if it's possible for your case - not the same, but was alternative for mine.

Additional `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-langX:Y.Z'` dependency gives you more than 3k LOC, at least in 2014, source: https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/