# Android change locale programatically to extended codes

Tags: java, android

I tried following https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/1067596 and it works with two letter codes, but doesn't work with codes like `b+zh+hans` or `pt-rBR`

Looks like `Locale` class cannot be directly instantiated with such values as if java doesn't understand them? Can such codes be set programatically without manually parsing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IETF BCP 47 language tags you can use the static method [`Locale.forLanguageTag(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String)). This is available since Android SDK 21. If you want to support lower SDK you can use commons-lang like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908927/1571117).

In order to comply with IETF BCP 47 the tags must be separated by hyphens (`-`). Your first example doesn't work, seems like it should be `zh-hans-...`. Your second runs but seems to be wrong, too. I guess it should be either  `pt-BR` or `pt-PT`.

Kindly note that the language tags are case-independent but country codes are usually written in all upper case

```
Locale chineseSimplifiedHongkong = Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-Hans-HK");
Locale portugueseBrazil = Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-BR");
```